# Rails get column names from all tables after join

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, parameters

I'm trying to get the column names from several tables having performed a join to combine them.

I tried just doing the following:

```
User.joins(:user_account, :user_file, :user_education).column_names
```

but this is only returning the column names from User, as if I had just done the following:

```
User.column_names
```

Does anyone know how to get all of the column names from a join? It seems that this isn't often needed because there doesn't seem to be much information about it online. I need it in order to validate user params.

Thanks!

EDIT:

column names in User table:

```
["id", "status", "accepted_terms", "created_at", "updated_at", "email", "encrypted_password", "reset_password_token", "reset_password_sent_at", "remember_created_at", "sign_in_count", "current_sign_in_at", "last_sign_in_at", "current_sign_in_ip", "last_sign_in_ip", "confirmation_token", "confirmed_at", "confirmation_sent_at", "unconfirmed_email", "provider", "uid"]
```

column names in User_account table:

```
 ["first_name", "last_name", "phone_number", "address"]
```

I want to be able to get an entire list of column names, i.e.

```
["id", "status", "accepted_terms", "created_at", "updated_at", "email", "encrypted_password", "reset_password_token", "reset_password_sent_at", "remember_created_at", "sign_in_count", "current_sign_in_at", "last_sign_in_at", "current_sign_in_ip", "last_sign_in_ip", "confirmation_token", "confirmed_at", "confirmation_sent_at", "unconfirmed_email", "provider", "uid", "first_name", "last_name", "phone_number", "address"]
```

What method do I need to get exactly that list? I have tried

```
User.joins(:user_account).column_names
```

but this just gives me the first set of column names, i.e. the ones in just the user table (not the ones in the user account table).

Comment: can you post the error that you are having

Comment: is what you are getting us the column that belong to User?

Comment: yes, exactly. (I added some more information if that helps).

Answer (score 2):

You can simply do this:

```
User.column_names + UserAccount.column_names
```

and so on. Rails retrieves column names from ActiveRecord class, not from SQL relation.

UPD. Or more idiomatic

```
[User, UserAccount, UserFile, UserEducation].flat_map(&:column_names).uniq
```

Answer (score 0):

This is ruby right?
I am not that familiar with that language and its Syntax, but depending clearly on MySQL knowledge, i think you are lacking how those tables connect with each other!
You can see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17147431/ruby-on-rails-joining-multiple-tables-and-how-to-extract-data) for more information that i think will help to solve your issue!

EDIT:
Post says:
Rails allows You to write custom join conditions inside a string, like this:

```
Reservation.joins('INNER JOIN "tables" ON "tables"."id" = "reservations"."table_id" INNER JOIN "users" ON "users"."id" = "reservations"."user_id"')
```

or much cleaner just specify several join clauses:

```
Reservation.join(:user).join(:table)
```

To extract data you need just apply a few custom select clauses, like this:

```
Reservation.join(:user).join(:table).select("tables.seats AS table_seats")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.

```
User.select("users.*, user_accounts.*, user_files.*, user_educations.*").joins(:joins(:user_account, :user_file, :user_education))
```

I hope that this helps.

Happy Hacking